# Sequence with anchoring property is convergent in finite dimension

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $(x_k)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Furthermore, assume that the sequence has the following "anchoring" property: $\exists y,z \in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\lim|x_k-y|=r_y$ and $\lim|x_k-z|=r_z$. Show that the sequence $(x_k)$ is convergent.

I have shown it's bounded:

$|x_k| \leq |x_k-y|+|y| < r_y + \varepsilon + |y| < \infty$.

From here I am not sure where to go. Any hints? I thought maybe I should use the sequential compactness of closed balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to find a convergent subsequence maybe?

Comment: are there other conditions such as $y \ne z$

Comment: Yeah $y\neq z$ of course otherwise it's not true (circle)

Comment: Given the answer below, it seems to be true only for $n=1$.

Comment: Shouldn't be $y,z\in \Bbb R$?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz they are in R^n.  OP writes |y|, but we understand than he/she means the norm of a vector.

Comment: Thank you......

Comment: I mean a norm of a vector and the way ive written it is correct, it's a convention thats frequently used. I specified the space the variables are in, there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you have $y \ne z$, the statement is still *incorrect*.  For a counterexample, take $n = 2$, and two *intersecting* circles centred at $y$ and $z$ with radii $r_y$ and $r_z$ respectively.  Take $(x_k)_k$ to be the sequence *oscillating* between the two points of intersection.  From the uniqueness of limit in Hausdorff spaces (e.g. $\Bbb{R}^n$), we know that $(x_k)_k$ *can't* be convergent.

$$
%
\def\place#1#2#3{\smash{\rlap{\hskip{#1em}\raise{#2em}{#3}}}}
%
\hskip 1em
%
\place{-3}{-0.5}{\Huge\bigcirc}
\place{-3}{0}{\bullet_{\large y}}
\place{-1}{-0.5}{\Huge\bigcirc}
\place{0.5}{0}{\bullet_{\large z}}
$$

Comment: agreed, if it converges it does in the intersection of two spheres but if they are not tangent it does not converges (but a sub sequence does)

Comment: You're right, but what if, instead of just two points $y$ and $z$, we assume the following instead: $\exists S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\forall s\in S, \lim|x_n-s|=r_s$ and int$S\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: You may try to see if it's Cauchy.  I *think* that's true, but I *don't* know how to prove that.  Why not start a new question, so that others can upvote and answer your question.

Comment: I will, but comments are partially intended for this sort of informal brainstorming iirc. Its possible you could answer decisively with a short reason and then i could revise the question to a more meaningful form before posting again. This would avoid too many similar posts.